# Unoriented graphs and hamiltonian roads

Tags: math, graph

What is the difference between hamiltonian roads and hamiltonian circuits? What I ask for is more than definitions, but some examples to make me understand easier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between a Hamiltonian path and cycle is that a cycle starts & ends at the same point, whereas a path can end at a different point.

Comment: An example of using the difference?

Comment: A linear graph consisting of a chain of nodes has a Hamiltonian path but no Hamiltonian cycle.